# angularjs localStorageServiceProvider

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to follow this tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A

**I don't know which angularjs package to download so that I could use localStorageService and ngAuthSettings in my angularjs code.**

I am getting the following err when I run the mvc 5 asp.net vs2013  web api app.

```
Unknown provider: localStorageServiceProvider <- localStorageService <- authInterceptorService <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile
```

Here is my code.

```
var appointmentReminderApp = angular.module('appointmentReminderApp', ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap"]);


appointmentReminderApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "App/Home.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        })
        .when("/Register", {
            templateUrl: "App/AuthForm/templates/register.html",
            controller: "authRegisterController"
        })
        .when("/Login", {
            templateUrl: "App/AuthForm/templates/login.html",
            controller: "authLoginController"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
});



appointmentReminderApp.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$injector', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $injector, $location, localStorageService) {

    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {

        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            var authService = $injector.get('authService');
            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');

            if (authData) {
                if (authData.useRefreshTokens) {
                    $location.path('/refresh');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            }
            authService.logOut();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);



appointmentReminderApp.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($http, $q, localStorageService, ngAuthSettings) {

        var registerUser = function (auth) {
            return $http.post("/api/Account/Register", auth);
        };

        var loginUser = function (loginData) {

            var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.Password;

            if (loginData.useRefreshTokens) {
                data = data + "&client_id=" + ngAuthSettings.clientId;
            }

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {

                if (loginData.useRefreshTokens) {
                    localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: response.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });
                }
                else {
                    localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: "", useRefreshTokens: false });
                }
                    _authentication.isAuth = true;
                    _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;
                    _authentication.useRefreshTokens = loginData.useRefreshTokens;

                    deferred.resolve(response);

                }).error(function (err, status) {
                    _logOut();
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });

                return deferred.promise;

        };

        return {
            registerUser: registerUser,
            loginUser: loginUser
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: From the error it seems you have injected `localStorageService` but angular is unable to find its provider. Make sure you are including the required js file since it doen't come bundled with angular.

Comment: That is the question I asked originally. Now I have bolded my original questions.

Comment: I was able to download it.. If you had provided your comment as an answer, I would have chosen it as correct one.

Comment: It's never too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you downloaded the angular local storage service module?  do you have this line

```
<script src="scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
```

in your index.html?

Comment: it looks like the version they are using is grevory's and can be found [on Github](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

The required JS file doen't come bundled with Angular.
You can get it from [here](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

I was unable to find the CDN, will update if I find one.